# 1980s comic where Spider-man is being strangled

Tags: story-identification, marvel, spider-man

I was looking for a comic book I saw in the mid 80s (or just 80s). I believe from a Spider-man comic book. The first page showed someone was strangling Spider-man while Spider-man was on his knees and then a large light came from behind the person who was strangling him.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is [*Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1 #289*](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_289), which was published in 1986, which closely relates to what you describe. Hobgoblin strangles Spider-man and he's on his knees.

[image]

The cover has him standing in a spotlight as if just revealed

[image]

Comment: No this wasn't it.  The  very first page of the comic has Spiderman on his knee in his Spiderman costume being strangled  by a person and  than the person turns around to see a light coming at him. Maybe cloak and dagger? not sure

Comment: I meant maybe the light is from Cloak and Dagger? Not sure at all!

Comment: That isn't Spidey being strangled there. It's the Earth-616 version of Ned Leeds, who was one of several people the original Hobgoblin brainwashed into serving as stand-ins for him (that's why he's wearing that costume). Ned was married to Jonah Jameson's secretary, Betty Brant, at the time, which is why she was in his thoughts. He was also a reporter for the Daily Bugle, working on an overseas assignment with Peter Parker (they were in Berlin), which is why Peter was in his thoughts as well.